# how to setValue in Two NumberPickers from float value

Tags: numberpicker

I have two numberpickers

```
NumberPicker np1 = (NumberPicker)container.findViewById(R.id.np1);
NumberPicker np2 = (NumberPicker)container.findViewById(R.id.np2);
```

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEjzt.jpg)

This:

```
String sValue = np1.getValue() + "." + np2.getValue();

textView.settext(sValue);
```

return for example 60.5

But i can't know how to put float value back

```
float f = (float)60.5;
```

in to my two numberPickers. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your numbers will only have 1 decimal place then you could do the following:

```
float f = 60.5f;

var left = Math.Truncate(f);    
var right = (f-left) * 10;

np1.setValue(left);
np2.setValue(right);
```

Comment: thanks!!! I meant for android. But your answer helped me.
float f = 60.5f;
int left = (int) f;
float f1 = (f - (float)left) * 10;
int right = (int)f1;